# How do I write my own launch files in Hydro?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin, ros-hydro, roshydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does this have to be done through the catkin process or can you simply create a necessary folder structure with the requisite files?  If so, how do you add it so that Hydro will recognize it since ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is used differently for Hydro than previous editions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115101/how-do-i-write-my-own-launch-files-in-hydro?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-06**:
I'm not sure to understand your problem correctly but if you want to add one folder as an extra work space you can do it in bashrc for example
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/working_space:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-06**:
Except that I've done that and it refuses to recognize any addition to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH that isn't in /opt/ros/~. I finally got one launch working by adding the fuerte path into the package path but I can't add any folders from my desktop. I'm not sure why.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-06**:\

1. Does it matter if I use cd && nano .bashrc to edit it?  I've already put my test directory in the .bashrc before and it didn't work to make roslaunch recognize my custom launch files.
2. I created the test package but I am unsure how this is used with launch files?

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-06**:
Hamid, it worked!  I can run any launch file by placing it in a launch folder in that test folder.  Why does it work that way?  I looked all over the tutorials and could not find this. Is it because roslaunch needs all of the other stuff in the test folder? Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

create one folder in your Desktop and open terminal type ($gedit .bashrc)  and at the end  write the following lines:
 (export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/Desktop/(folder name):$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)
close terminal and open terminal again go to folder that you created type($roscreate-pkg test)
and then type ($rosmake test) try this
note: don't forget after you edited bashrc you must close the terminal and open it agian

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-06**:
when you create new work space and then create test pkg.test pkg directory add like other pkg directory in ros. when you call this pkg in launch file launch file can find your pkg

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-07**:
Thank you!